# Address out of bounds in C

Tags: c

I'm making a program that manipulates files using indices, but I'm facing a problem that is blocking me when I try debugging one of my functions: "Address 0x6 out of bounds". I've really searched on the net and also here on StackOverflow, and I found similar questions but none of them helped me solve my problem. The code is really long (~2300 lines) so I'll just put the bit of code that generates for me the error (I'm not sure about that but at least nothing happens before it)

```
char s[21]="";
   int bi, bs;
   scanf("%s", s);
   scanf("%d", &bi);
   scanf("%d", &bs);
   consultRMA(fichier,bi, bs, s, tabRM, AgeIndx,tableIndexPrim);
```

here's the function consultRMA

```
    int consultRMA(LnOVC *f, char region[MAX_REG_MILIT], int bIAge, int bSAge, indexSecondRegMilit tab[6], tabIndxAge IndxAge, index_primaire tabPrm[])
/** consulter tout les enregistrement relatifs a une region militaire region ayant un age entre deux valeurs bIAge et bSAge (resp.)*/
{
    int i, m = 0,n, k, r;
    if (strcmp(region, "1RM-Blida") == 0)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < tab[0].nbMatric; i++)
        {
            if(tab[0].tab[i].suppr == 0)
            {
                for(m = 0; m < IndxAge.taille; m++)
                {
                    if((IndxAge.tab[m].age >= bIAge) && (IndxAge.tab[m].age <= bSAge))
                    {
                        for(n = 0; n < IndxAge.tab[m].nbMatric; n++)
                        {
                            if(IndxAge.tab[m].tab[n].matricule == tab[0].tab[i].matricule)
                            {
                                k = rechIndexPrim(tab[0].tab[i].matricule, tabPrm, *f);
                                if(k != -1)
                                {
                                    r = tabPrm[k].pos;
                                    afficheEnreg(f, tabPrm[k].n_bloc, &r);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }else if (strcmp(region, "2RM-Oran") == 0)
         {
            for(i = 0; i < tab[1].nbMatric; i++)
            {
                if(tab[1].tab[i].suppr == 0)
                {
                    for(m = 0; m < IndxAge.taille; m++)
                    {
                        if((IndxAge.tab[m].age >= bIAge) && (IndxAge.tab[m].age <= bSAge))
                        {
                            for(n = 0; n < IndxAge.tab[m].nbMatric; n++)
                            {
                                if(IndxAge.tab[m].tab[n].matricule == tab[1].tab[i].matricule)
                                {
                                    k = rechIndexPrim(tab[1].tab[i].matricule, tabPrm, *f);
                                    if(k != -1)
                                    {
                                        r = tabPrm[k].pos;
                                        afficheEnreg(f, tabPrm[k].n_bloc, &r);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }else if (strcmp(region, "3RM-Bechar") == 0)
            {
                for(i = 0; i < tab[2].nbMatric; i++)
                {
                    if(tab[2].tab[i].suppr == 0)
                    {
                        for(m = 0; m < IndxAge.taille; m++)
                        {
                            if((IndxAge.tab[m].age >= bIAge) && (IndxAge.tab[m].age <= bSAge))
                            {
                                for(n = 0; n < IndxAge.tab[m].nbMatric; n++)
                                {
                                    if(IndxAge.tab[m].tab[n].matricule == tab[2].tab[i].matricule)
                                    {
                                        k = rechIndexPrim(tab[2].tab[i].matricule, tabPrm, *f);
                                        if(k != -1)
                                        {
                                            r = tabPrm[k].pos;
                                            afficheEnreg(f, tabPrm[k].n_bloc, &r);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }else if (strcmp(region, "4RM-Ouargla") == 0)
            {
                    for(i = 0; i < tab[3].nbMatric; i++)
                        {
                            if(tab[3].tab[i].suppr == 0)
                            {
                                for(m = 0; m < IndxAge.taille; m++)
                                {
                                    if((IndxAge.tab[m].age >= bIAge) && (IndxAge.tab[m].age <= bSAge))
                                    {
                                        for(n = 0; n < IndxAge.tab[m].nbMatric; n++)
                                        {
                                            if(IndxAge.tab[m].tab[n].matricule == tab[3].tab[i].matricule)
                                            {
                                                k = rechIndexPrim(tab[3].tab[i].matricule, tabPrm, *f);
                                                if(k != -1)
                                                {
                                                    r = tabPrm[k].pos;
                                                    afficheEnreg(f, tabPrm[k].n_bloc, &r);
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }else if (strcmp(region, "5RM-Constantine") == 0)
                        {
                    for(i = 0; i < tab[4].nbMatric; i++)
                    {
                        if(tab[4].tab[i].suppr == 0)
                        {
                            for(m = 0; m < IndxAge.taille; m++)
                            {
                                if((IndxAge.tab[m].age >= bIAge) && (IndxAge.tab[m].age <= bSAge))
                                {
                                    for(n = 0; n < IndxAge.tab[m].nbMatric; n++)
                                    {
                                        if(IndxAge.tab[m].tab[n].matricule == tab[4].tab[i].matricule)
                                        {
                                            k = rechIndexPrim(tab[4].tab[i].matricule, tabPrm, *f);
                                            if(k != -1)
                                            {
                                                r = tabPrm[k].pos;
                                                afficheEnreg(f, tabPrm[k].n_bloc, &r);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }else if (strcmp(region, "6RM-Tamanrasset") == 0)
                    {
                        for(i = 0; i < tab[5].nbMatric; i++)
                        {
                            if(tab[5].tab[i].suppr == 0)
                            {
                                for(m = 0; m < IndxAge.taille; m++)
                                {
                                    if((IndxAge.tab[m].age >= bIAge) && (IndxAge.tab[m].age <= bSAge))
                                    {
                                        for(n = 0; n < IndxAge.tab[m].nbMatric; n++)
                                        {
                                            if(IndxAge.tab[m].tab[n].matricule == tab[5].tab[i].matricule)
                                            {
                                                k = rechIndexPrim(tab[5].tab[i].matricule, tabPrm, *f);
                                                if(k != -1)
                                                {
                                                    r = tabPrm[k].pos;
                                                    afficheEnreg(f, tabPrm[k].n_bloc, &r);
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I debug, I find in the watches that string s is: "Address 0x6 is out of bounds"!! How can I fix this issue?

Comment: _Questions seeking debugging help (why isn't this code working?) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]._

Comment: @SouravGhosh thnx a lot for the comment i'll check the article right away.

Comment: Either the problem is somewhere in the `consultRMA` function or the string input for the first `scanf` is longer than 20 characters which will cause a buffer overflow for `s` which might trigger the error you get.

Comment: @MichaelWalz no I'm sure the problem is not in consultRMA because I'm not even able to execute the first 2 instructions in it because "Address out of bouns" is generating a segmentation error in the first line in consultRMA  where i use strcpy, and for the string input it never passes 10 caracteres, I even check the contant of s and it is correct. Thnx A LOT for your help though.

Comment: @DrSimplisist your last comment is contradictory. The problem clearly is within the `consultRMA` function because you get a segmentation error  during the call of `strcpy`. If you want help you need to [edit] your question and show us at least the first few lines of  `consultRMA`.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I'm having the segmentation error because the vriable s is out of bounds, so that's the real issue, the segmentation error in the function consultRMA is just a manifistation of that problem, at least that's what i believe

Comment: BTW: the `consultRMA` could probbaly be 5-6 times shorter.

Comment: Uggghh... *Please* learn about things like factoring out to functions, using `continue`, `break`, early `return`, and such - to avoid monstrosities of indentation like that. If your code can be rewritten to avoid extra levels of indentation, write it that way instead.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I can't see how to make it shorter, please pardon my ignorance, but can you tell me how?

Comment: @underscore_d can you reference me to a useful source to learn about how to use them in such a case please?

Comment: You have 6 almost identical loops that differ only by the index used in `tab[1]`, `tab[2]` etc. Do I need to say more?

Comment: Well, anything like `for ... { if (thing) { indented_stuff(); } }` can be much better represented as `for ... { if (!thing) { continue; } /* non_indented_stuff(); }`, for starters.

Comment: @MichaelWalz  mmm i add a function in which i put all that's inside the big if else and instead of writing all that jumble i'll just call taht function?

Comment: @DrSimplisist that's a possibility.

Comment: @MichaelWalz i add a vaiable that will reference to the case i'm in (example: if (strcmp(region, "1RM-Blida") == 0)  { i =0; } ) and then write all that only once by replacing tab[1], tab[2] etc. by tab[i]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters you pass to the `consultRMA` don't match:

The prototype of `consultRMA` is:

```
int consultRMA(LnOVC *f, char region[MAX_REG_MILIT], int bIAge, int bSAge,
               indexSecondRegMilit tab[6], tabIndxAge IndxAge, index_primaire tabPrm[]);
```

but you call it like this:

```
consultRMA(fichier, bi, bs, s, tabRM, AgeIndx, tableIndexPrim);
```

but it should probably be called like this:

```
consultRMA(fichier, s, bi, bs, tabRM, AgeIndx, tableIndexPrim);
```

If you had enabled all compiler warnings you would have got a warning that the parameters don't match (which is actually more like an error).

Comment: OMG thanks so suuuper much I can't believe the reason was such a stupid error, i checked the parametres but i was so tired i didn't notice x))))))) THANKS INFINITELY